# MySQL case matching all conditions

Tags: mysql, case

I have functionality something like this,

> select
>  case 
>  when purchase_date <= '2017-12-31' then (update
>   report_table set year=2017 where item_id='..')  
>  when
>   purchase_date <= '2018-03-31' then (update report_table set year=2018
>   where item_id='..') 
>  else null end as year_purchase ...

If have a item purchased on Dec 30, 2017 that should satisfy both conditions.

By referring to MySQL guide, it says that it can do only if then else statement. How do I achieve multiple if statement so that both my conditions execute.

I even tried with if condition but no luck.

Comment: `that should satisfy both conditions` ... the year can only be set to a single value.  Which value should it be for Dec 30, 2017?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler approach would be to just assign the `year` column directly to the year value of the date:

```
UPDATE report_table
SET year = YEAR(purchase_date)
WHERE YEAR(purchase_date) IN (2017, 2018) AND item_id = <some_value>;
```

But I don't see the point of persisting the year number by itself in a separate column in your table, since it can easily be derived from the full date, and since it would mean wasting some space.

Comment: In my case, I want it to update both 2017 & 2018 into it. Which means both update statements should execute.

Comment: @Sekhar That doesn't make any sense, since for a single record, there can only be one `year` value.  You might not even know which value gets assigned.  Can you clarify what you are trying to do here?

Comment: From report table, they will generate some reports. So, this purchase should reflect in both reports when they run for 2017 and 2018 as well. Basically, those reports are as of date basis. It will get all the purchases till date.

Comment: You can't do that.  MySQL can't generate records which were not already there.  Looking now, you would need a union for this.

Comment: By doing union all and separated the conditions it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sekhar You should post your own answer.  Afterwards, I can delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

> select * from(
>  select
>  case 
>  when purchase_date <=
>   '2017-12-31' then (select amount)
>  end as purchase_amount 
>   **union all** 
>  select
>  case 
>  when purchase_date <= '2018-03-31' then (select amount)
>  end as purchase_amount)

Using union all done the work.